# Why doesn't SQL Server sys.objects contain all the stored procedures, etc in my database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008, sometimes I can query `sys.objects` and get information about any stored procedure in the database. At other times, it doesn't work. Just now, I tried this query:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 name FROM sys.objects
```

...And got back only 6 records: `spt_fallback_db`, `spt_fallback_dev`, `spt_fallback_usg`, `spt_monitor`, `spt_values`, and `DF__spt_value__statu__4460231C`.

That is on a database with more than 10,000 stored procedures. What gives?

Comment: with the data provided i would dare to guess your not logged in as a user authorized to see more then that. can you check for that and if it's not the answer provide more data?

Comment: Are your sure you're using the right database? Every database has it's own `sys.objects`. You can also check if `select object_id('YourUspName')` returns null.

Comment: @AdamŁuniewski, I do have access to more than one DB in SSMS. But none of them have only 6 objects.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to make sure that your login has the `VIEW DEFINITION` permission set. As in:

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO MyUser
```

Of course you can also set the permission through SSMS.